# How to auto-refresh a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller and a view with a div :

```
def show
  @requests = events.get_requests
end
```

`get_requests` returns all the requests in the database with a select, which I output in a div in my view:

```
<div class="party-block" id="requests">
  <h4><%= t '.requests' %></h4>
  <input type="button" value="<%= t '.refresh' %>" onClick="window.location.reload()" class="btn-sm btn-info">
  <% @requests.each do |r| %>
    <span class="request">
      ...
```

In this div I print all requests with other things.

I want to automatically refresh this div with a JavaScript/jQuery function. For the moment I use a button to refresh but do I need to re-execute the code in my controller?

Comment: You want to refresh it in a certain interval? Or you want to refresh the div with a button but without refreshing the page(asynchronously)?

Comment: I need to refresh div every 2 seconds if it is possible. I was also asking myself if it wasn't too heavy for the database to refresh it every 2 seconds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't care about your expertise or primary language, we want well thought-out questions. If you have difficulty with English we'll help make the question more understandable. I'd highly recommend reading the linked pages in "[ask]", especially http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. It's long but has really good tips on how to ask in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in JavaScript named `setInterval` that lets you schedule a function to be executed every time interval.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
setInterval(function() { 
  console.log("Hi There");
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: The problem is i have @requests in my controller and the display in my view. I need to fuse it in a single view ?

Comment: I would convert the whole thing to an ajax call and do the updates in javascript rather than the rails view